# Acquiring offset of some row in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

TL;DR: Is there a possibility to *get* `OFFSET` position of a particular, known row in SQL, considering some `ORDER BY` is applied?

So consider a schema like this (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."painting" (
    "uuid" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "name" varchar NOT NULL,
    "score" int4 NOT NULL,
    "approvedAt" timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ("uuid")
);
```

Like

- `abc1,test1,10,10:00`
- `abc2,test2,9,11:00`
- `abc3,test3,8,8:00`
- `abc4,test4,8,12:00`
- `abc5,test5,6,7:00`

I want to make a request sorted by score and limited with 3 items, and I should emphasize that multiple entities might have the same score.

Because of a dynamic nature of that table, while traversing through those items, sorted by score, some new item might appear somewhere in the list.

If I use SQL `OFFSET` statement, that means this new entity will shift all entities below to one row, so that the new selection will have an item, that was last on previous 3 items selection.

- `abc1,test1,10,10:00`
- `abc2,test2,9,11:00`
- `abc6,test6,8,15:00` (new item)
- CURRENT OFFSET = 3
- `abc3,test3,8,8:00` (was in previous select)
- `abc4,test4,8,12:00`
- `abc5,test5,6,7:00`

To avoid that, instead of using `OFFSET`, I can remember the UUID of the item I fetched last, so it'll be `abc3`. On next request, I can use it's `score` to add an extra `WHERE SCORE < 8` statement, but this will skip `abc4`, because it's too having score of 8.
If I use `WHERE SCORE <= 8` this will again return `abc3` which is already traversed. I can't use another field in `WHERE` clause, because this will affect the results. Additional `ORDER BY` won't help either.

It seems to me that it is a very common problem in database selection, yet I can't find one comprehensive answer.

So, my question then, if it's possible to do some kind of request like following:

```
SELECT * FROM "painting" WHERE "score" <= :score ORDER BY "score" DESC OFFSET %position of `abc3`% LIMIT 3
```

Or alternatively

```
SELECT OFFSET OF (`abc3`) FROM "painting" WHERE SCORE <= :score ORDER BY "score" DESC LIMIT 3
```

That will return 2 (because it's the second row with such score), then do

```
SELECT * FROM "painting" WHERE "score" <= :score ORDER BY "score" DESC OFFSET :offset LIMIT 3
```

where :score is the score of last received item and :offset is the result of `SELECT OFFSET` - 1

My own assumption is that we have to `SELECT WHERE "score" = :score`, and get offset position outside the SQL (or make a very complex SQL query). Though, if we have a lot of items with similar `ORDER BY` attribute, this helper request might end up being heavier than the data fetch itself.

Yet, I feel like that there's a much more clever SQL way of doing what I'm trying to do.

Comment: As far as I understand, you're concerned about new items while you're querying the data? Why don't you just add another column `created`, which gets the TIMESTAMP when the row was added. Then you can filter the rows, e.g. only rows before some point in time.

Comment: (I'm not sure if your column `approvedAt` already contains the information, when the row was added.)

Comment: @Alex Gru, that's a good option for sure! I'm more looking for a best practice to make a "continue from" SQL pagination instead of basic OFFSET pagination, which can be unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. Accurate *Backend Pagination* requires the underlying data to use an ordering criteria with a set of columns that represent a UNIQUE key.

In your case your ordering criteria can be made unique by adding the column `uuid` to it. With that in mind you can increase the page size by 1 behind the scenes to 4. That 4th row won't be displayed but only used to retrieve the next page.

For example, you can get:

```
select *
from painting
order by -score, approvedAt, uuid
limit 4
```

Now you would display the first three rows:

```
abc1,test1,10,10:00
abc2,test2,9,11:00
abc3,test3,8,8:00
```

The client app (most likely the UI) will remember -- not display -- the 4th row (the "key") to retrieve the next page:

```
abc4,test4,8,12:00
```

Then, to get the next page the query will add a `WHERE` clause with the "key" and take the form:

```
select *
from painting
where (-score, approvedAt, uuid) >= (-8, '12:00', 'abc4')
order by -score, approvedAt, uuid
limit 4
```

This query won't display the new row being inserted, but the original 4th row.

To get blazing fast data retrieval you could create the index:

```
create index ix1 on painting ((-score), approvedAt, uuid);
```

See example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/obFLC7gaa1RBvTfNeHMDQA/0).

Comment: That is a very interesting and clean way to solve that problem, exactly what I was looking for. I thought to make use of other keys somehow, but had no idea that it is possible to use complex key for where clause. Brilliant, thank you very much.